# "Exception was thrown. Read more in log file." when running the xDB Data Migration Tool Troubleshooter

Tags: xdb, data-migration

I am following the [xDB Data Migration Tool 2.1 Installation Guide](https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/3098ADAA80444031A9E1D938A212C67A.ashx).

I am using Sitecore 9.1, and I have installed all of the required packages (Data Exchange Framework 2.1, MongoDB Provider for Data Exchange Framework 2.1, xConnect Provider for Data Exchange Framework 2.1, xDB Data Migration Tool for Data Exchange Framework 2.1).

I have followed all the steps up to **1.4.5. Configure an endpoint**, until point 8) when I get asked to run the Troubleshooter; when I do so, I get the following error message:

*Exception was thrown. Read more in log file. An error occurred while sending the request.*

I have XConnect configured correctly. I can access the URL of both the Collection and Search Indexer endpoints - although Chrome and Brave complain about the self-signed certificates.

The Sitecore log contains no mention of any problem, as does the Windows Event Viewer.

**EDIT**

Here is the content of the XConnect Collection log:

```
2019-05-10 13:42:08.712 +01:00 [Information] Certificate Validation Filter Enabled, Thumbprint: 621B26950DC9DE426493B9698ECA36CDBD4CD26A
2019-05-10 13:42:08.712 +01:00 [Information] SSL Validation Filter Enabled
2019-05-10 14:24:04.897 +01:00 [Information] XConnect Test Host Application End, Machine: "LTLON-ECIRIACH", Site: "XPScaled910.collection", AppId: "/LM/W3SVC/8/ROOT"
```

No error message whatsoever is contained. The SSL Thumbprint, confusingly enough, is different from the one I retrieve from the mmc console. Even after using that, the error message persists.

**EDIT 2**

Eventually I fired dotPeek and debugged the backgound process, and found the error in the following class: Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.XConnect.Troubleshooters.TestXConnectClientEndpointConnection, and specifically inside the

*protected virtual IXdbContext GetXConnectClient(XConnectClientEndpointSettings settings)*

method. When debugging the very first line of this method and inspecting settings.ClientHelper, I get the following error message:

*The target process exited with code -2146233082 while evaluating the function 'System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.Listeners.get'.
If the probleme happens regularly, consider disabling the Tools->Options settings "Debugging->General->Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls" or debugging the cause by evaluating the expression from the Immediate window. See help for more information on doing this.*

**Question**

Any idea on what is causing this error?

Comment: Have you verified that the collection service and collection service certificate connection strings match what is in your connectionstrings.config? Also have you tried to check the "allow invalid certificates" checkbox?

Comment: Yes and yes sadly.

Comment: Can you check the xConnect log file for an issue.

Comment: I edited the question with the log information.